# How to reduce a massive matrix conditioned on a specific variable that does not contain NA

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dplyr, reduce

I have an enormous "omics" dataset containing three different experiments: `df$method == Mut, Spy, VAR`

```
  method    a    b    c    d
1    Mut 12.3   NA   NA 17.5
2    Spy 13.5   NA   NA   NA
3    VAR 13.2 19.6 11.1   NA
4    Mut   NA   NA   NA   NA
5    Spy   NA   NA   NA 19.9
6    VAR   NA 20.1 18.6   NA
```

Using `dplyr`, how can I reduce the matrix so it *only* contains rows where `df$method == VAR` has values (at least one value)? I.e., where all values in `a, b, c, d ...` is `NA` for `df$method == Mut, Spy`.

Shown on a Venn Diagramm, values that fits in the white area, are of interest.

[image]

So, the expected output from `df` would be:

```
> df
  method    b    c
1    VAR 19.6 11.1
2    VAR 20.1 18.6
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(method = c("Mut", "Spy", "VAR", "Mut", "Spy",
                                "VAR"), a = c(12.3, 13.5, 13.2, NA, NA, NA), b = c(NA, NA, 19.6,
                                                                                   NA, NA, 20.1), c = c(NA, NA, 11.1, NA, NA, 18.6), d = c(17.5,
                                                                                                                                           NA, NA, NA, 19.9, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                                                                                                                                       -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` option to first filter the method and then select the columns with no NA's like this:

```r
df <- structure(list(method = c("Mut", "Spy", "VAR", "Mut", "Spy",
                                "VAR"), a = c(12.3, 13.5, 13.2, NA, NA, NA), b = c(NA, NA, 19.6,
                                                                                   NA, NA, 20.1), c = c(NA, NA, 11.1, NA, NA, 18.6), d = c(17.5,
                                                                                                                                           NA, NA, NA, 19.9, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                                                                                                                                       -6L))
library(dplyr)
library(dplyr)   
df %>%
  filter(method == "VAR") %>%
  select_if(~!any(is.na(.)))
#>   method    b    c
#> 1    VAR 19.6 11.1
#> 2    VAR 20.1 18.6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Does your approach imply that *all* corresponding columns in Spy and Mut is *only* `NA`?

Comment: Hi @cmirian, it selects the columns that has no `NA` in them, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R way. Use logical indices to get the rows where `method == "VAR"` and the columns where the other rows, the rows with `method` is equal to `"Spy"` or `"Mut"` are all `NA`.

```r
df <- structure(list(
  method = c("Mut", "Spy", "VAR", "Mut", "Spy","VAR"), 
  a = c(12.3, 13.5, 13.2, NA, NA, NA), 
  b = c(NA, NA, 19.6,NA, NA, 20.1), 
  c = c(NA, NA, 11.1, NA, NA, 18.6), 
  d = c(17.5,NA, NA, NA, 19.9, NA)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L))

i_row <- df$method == "VAR"
i_col <- colSums(is.na(df[!i_row, -1])) == nrow(df[!i_row,])
df[i_row, c(TRUE, i_col)]
#>   method    b    c
#> 3    VAR 19.6 11.1
#> 6    VAR 20.1 18.6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>